# MySQLi Array in PHP sometimes coming up empty

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Okay, so I'm pretty much at the end of my rope trying to discover the issue here, because sometimes this code works perfectly, and then sometimes not, so here it is:

```
$allItems = array();
$allItemsQuery = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM cart_items WHERE crt_id='".$row['crt_id']."' AND quantity>0");
while($itemsArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allItemsQuery)){
    array_push($allItems,$itemsArray['item_id']);
}
$allItemsNames = array();
foreach($allItems as $key => $value){
    $itemNames = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM items WHERE id='$value'"));
    array_push($allItemsNames, $itemNames['item_name']);
}
$allItemsFinal = array_combine($allItems,$allItemsNames);
$itemsList = 'Items:<br>';
foreach($allItemsFinal as $key => $value){
    $itemsList .='<a href="http://www.exampleurl.org/product.php?ID='.$key.'">'.$value.'</a><br><br>';
}
```

The idea is it's supposed to get all of the item ID's the user has in their cart from the DB and put it into an array, which I've established exists, grab all of the item names based on their ID, and put that into an array, and then combine the two arrays as a key and value. Then I output the data from the arrays into a string.

This code works perfectly sometimes, and then suddenly not. Can somebody give me any idea why? I'd be indebted forever.

Comment: what is the error(s) this is producing? knowing what the error(s) is goes a long way in solving the problem

Comment: That's the weird part about it-it doesn't appear to be producing any errors, it just produces an empty string. Up until it starts producing an empty string, however, it can be working for quite some time.

Comment: well if there are no errors then it's probably a data issue, perhaps it's just not finding anything in certain scenarios, thus there's nothing in your $allItems variable. see if you can track down the input combination that is used when the empty string is produced. If your query(es) for that input combo are empty then there's you're cause.

Comment: Use `JOIN` instead of several queries.

Comment: That's horrible code. you simply assume that queries can never fail, and REALLY need to learn about JOINs...

Comment: Wouldn't splitting it up into multiple queries like this actually make it more modular, and make it easier to spot the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should throw this code away and use something like this:

```
$items = array();
$itemsQuery = "SELECT i.item_name, i.item_id 
    FROM items i WHERE i.item_id 
    IN (SELECT ci.item_id 
        FROM cart_items 
        WHERE crt_id='".$row['crt_id']."' 
        AND quantity>0
    )");

$allItemsQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $itemsQuery);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allItemsQuery))
    $items[$row['item_id']] = $items[$row['item_name']];
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried this and it seemed to fix the problem!